# Does a quasi-split reductive group scheme admit a maximal torus?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G \to S$ a reductive group scheme over arbitrary base. Following the conventions from Conrad's Reductive Group Schemes [notes](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf), we define a Borel subgroup to be an $S$-subgroup scheme $B \subseteq G$ which is a Borel subgroup in each algebraically closed fiber $\overline{s}: \operatorname{Spec} \overline{k} \to S$, and call $G$ **quasi-split** if it admits a Borel subgroup. We likewise call a torus **maximal** if it is maximal in each algebraically closed fiber.

A technical obstruction to applying the usual weight theory and dynamic descriptions of parabolics and Levis is the possible nonexistence of a maximal torus (except Zariski-locally). Does being quasi-split remedy this? That is, does every quasi-split reductive group scheme admit a maximal torus?

I am especially interested in the case where $S$ is a (smooth proper geometrically connected) curve (over a finite field). If the claim holds or can be explicitly characterized in this case, that would be interesting.

#### My thoughts

If $S$ is affine, then my claim is true: this is handled in Conrad's notes by filtering the unipotent radical by vector bundles, then applying descent for vector bundles and affine vanishing for coherent cohomology.

There are many counterexamples to the claim "every parabolic has a Levi" in general, so this suggests that if this works here, something special about "solvability" of Borels is relevant.

Of course, even over imperfect fields, the semidirect decomposition of solvable groups [may not exist](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/appbnew.pdf), but the counterexamples in that paper emphasize the poor behavior of the unipotent radical under inseparable base change (though being over a field, maximal tori exist in these examples). We are asking for much less than a semidirect decomposition here.

The functor of maximal tori is representable by a smooth affine surjection $\operatorname{Tor} \to S$, but I don't know enough about its structure for "solvable" $B$ to characterize whether it should admit a section or not (and the proof that it does Zariski-locally is hard).

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164987/does-every-reductive-group-scheme-admit-a-maximal-torus

Comment: Do you want the maximal torus to be in the given Borel? In that case, I think you can break it. Let $S=\text{Fl}_2$ be the space of Borels in $\text{GL}_2$, let $G = \text{GL}_2 \times_k S$ and let your Borel be the tautological family inside $G$. But of course, since this is a split group scheme, it does have a maximal torus not in the given Borel.

Comment: I think one of the answers at the linked question adapts: let $E$ an indecomposable, but not irreducible, rank 2 vector bundle on $S = \mathbb{P}^2$. Then I believe $\operatorname{GL}(E)$ admits a Borel corresponding to the filtration, but by the argument given there it has no torus. I don't see a way to make this counterexample work for curves, though.

Comment: Doesn't the same idea work? According to https://mathoverflow.net/a/45328/297 , every vector bundle over a curve has a filtration by line bundles, and I know that indecomposable vector bundles over curves of positive genus exist.

Comment: You'd need the vector bundle not only to be indecomposable over $C$, but also over unbranched covers of $C$, but I bet you can get that.

Comment: Every vector bundle is trivial (hence decomposable) over some etale (unbranched) cover, no?

Comment: I think we are mixing up etale covers  and unbranched covers. If $C = \bigcup U_i$, then $\bigsqcup U_i \to C$ is etale, but it's not a covering map in the sense of topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\cO{\mathcal{O}}\def\cE{\mathcal{E}}\def\cG{\mathcal{G}}\def\cB{\mathcal{B}}\def\cT{\mathcal{T}}\def\GG{\mathbb{G}}\def\GL{\text{GL}}\def\PP{\mathbb{P}}$The answer is no. This answer fills in the details of an argument sketched in the comments.

Let $k$ be a field where $2 \neq 0$ and let $S$ be an elliptic curve over $k$. Then $\text{Ext}_S^1(\cO, \cO) = H^1(S, \cO)$ is one dimensional. Let
$$0 \to \cO \to \cE \to \cO \to 0 \qquad (\ast)$$
by the extension corresponding to a nonzero class in $H^1(S, \cO)$. Recall that proportional nonzero classes in $\text{Ext}_S^1(\cO, \cO)$ correspond to isomorphic vector bundles, so $\cE$ doesn't depend on choosing a particular element in $H^1(S, \cO)$. Let $\cG = \GL(\cE)$, a group scheme over $S$ whose geometric fibers are $\GL_2$. Let $\cB$ be the subgroup scheme of $\cG$ preserving the filtration $(\ast)$; then $\cB$ is a Borel, so $\cG$ is quasisplit. I claim, however, that there is no maximal torus $\cT$ in $\cG$.

Suppose, to the contrary, that such a torus $\cT$ exists. Let $\PP(\cE)$ be the projectivation of $\cE$, a $\PP^1$-bundle over $S$. Let $\Lambda \subset \PP(\cE)$ be the closed subscheme corresponding to eigenspaces of $\cT$. So there are two geometric points of $\Lambda$ over each geometric point of $S$. Since $\Lambda$ is a closed subscheme of the projective bundle $\PP(\cE)$, the map $\pi: \Lambda \to S$ is finite, and is a finite unramified map of degree $2$. The pullback $\pi^{\ast} \cE$ of $\cE$ to $\Lambda$ splits as $L_1 \oplus L_2$: At a geometric point $(v,s)$ of $\Lambda$, with $s \in S$ and $v$ corresponding to an eigenspace in $\cE_s$, the line bundle $L_1$ is the eigenspace $v$ and the line bundle $L_2$ is the other eigenspace.

If $\Lambda \to S$ is a trivial cover, this shows that $\cE$ is decomposable, which is not true. (See, for example, Lemma 16 in Atiyah, [Vector bundles over an elliptic curve](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Enadler/atiyah.classification.pdf), and note that Atiyah's notation $\cE(r,d)$ means the set of **indecomposable** vector bundles of rank $r$ and degree $d$.)

If $\Lambda \to S$ is a nontrivial cover, then it factors as $S \to \Lambda \to S$, where the composite map $S \to S$ is the doubling map $[2]$ in the elliptic curve $S$. Then we deduce that $[2]^{\ast} \mathcal{E}$ is decomposable.

Applying $[2]^{\ast}$ to the short exact sequence $(\ast)$, we obtain a sequence
$$0 \to \cO \to [2]^{\ast} \cE \to \cO \to 0.$$
So $[2]^{\ast} \cE$ corresponds to a class in $\text{Ext}^1(\cO, \cO) = H^1(S, \cO)$. More specifically, the induced map $[2]^{\ast} : H^1(S, \cO) \to H^1(S, \cO)$ is multiplication by $2$. Since $2 \neq 0$, we obtain that $[2]^{\ast} \cE$ is also a nontrivial extension of $\cO$ by itself, so $[2]^{\ast} \cE$ is isomorphic to $\cE$ as a vector bundle, and we deduce that $[2]^{\ast} \cE$ is indecomposable, a contradiction. $\square$.